# How to replace the break with a comma after two words?

Tags: javascript, replace, ms-word, imacros

I use the following line of code to replace all spaces with commas between words.

```
SET keyword-virgula EVAL("var spatiu=\"{{Keyword}}\"; spatiu.replace(/ /g,','); ")
```

How could I make the comma be added after two words?

```
word word, word word, word word, word word, word word,
```

Can someone help me?
thanks

I am using:
Browser: Google Chrome Version 105.0.5195.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)

iMacros Personal Edition License - Addon for Chrome -Version 10.1.1

Windows 10 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match 2 times one or more non whitespace characters followed by 1+ whitespace character in between using a pattern.

In the replacement use the full match using `$&` followed by a comma.

```js
const s = "word word word word word word word word word word";
const regex = /\S+\s+\S+/g
console.log(s.replace(regex, "$&,"));
```

Comment: What I do wrong?   SET keyword-commas EVAL("var s=\"{{Keyword}}\"; regex=/\S+\s+\S+/g;  s.replace(regex, "$&,");")

Comment: @IonutBejinariu Does it work like this? `SET keyword-commas EVAL("var s='word word word word word word word word word word'; regex=/\S+\s+\S+/g; s.replace(regex, '$&,');")`

Comment: It is working, thank you so much.. what I did Wrong?

Comment: @IonutBejinariu I am not sure, maybe it had to do with the quotes?

Answer (score 0):

With JS we can achieve , i hv no idea in Regex

```js
var str  = "word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word ";

   var strr = str.split(' ')
   .reduce(function (str, part, i) {
      return str + ((i%2)===0 ? ',' : ' ') + part
   });
console.log(strr);
```